# What is the effect of V(CE) to saturation?

Tags: transistors, saturation

I am following [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/transistors/operation-modes) tutorial about transistors. In the tutorial, it is stated that to be in the cutoff region, \$V_{BE}<0\$ and \$V_{BC}<0\$ must be true. The tutorial also states that however it is enough for \$V_{BE}<V_{th}\$ to be in the cutoff region.

My question is, which operating mode would the transistor be in the following:

$$ V_{BE} \ge V_{th} \;\; AND \;\; V_{CE} < V_{CE(sat)}$$

In this configuration, we know that \$V_B>V_E\$ from the fact that \$V_{BE} \ge V_{th}\$. We also know that \$V_B>V_C\$. We know this from the fact that \$V_{CE}<V_{CE(sat)}\$ but since \$V_{CE(sat)}<V_{th}\$, \$V_B\$ must be greater than \$V_C\$.

NOTE: It is completely my assumption that \$V_{CE(sat)}<V_{th}\$ must be the case. I am not sure if this is indeed correct. I have reached this assumption because the article states that usual values for \$ V_{th}\$ are around 0.6V and for \$ V_{CE(sat)}\$, they are around 0.2V. Please inform me if this is a wrong assumption.

So *per voltages*, we should be in the saturation mode (because \$ V_B > V_C \; AND \; V_B > V_E \$ ) but \$V_{CE}\$ is less than \$V_{CE(sat)}\$, so we cannot be in saturation mode either.

So which mode is the transistor in in this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You believe that when Vce is less than Vce(sat) you cannot be in saturation. This is incorrect. In saturation, Vce can be less than or equal to Vce sat.

Really, the way to look at it is this: If the base emitter junction is forward biased AND the base collector junction is also forward biased, then the transistor is in saturation. This is a simpler way to look at it, in my opinion. So, in the case you describe, the transistor is indeed saturated.

The terminology you use, with Vth, is not really standard terminology for BJT's. FYI.

Comment: In that case, there is an error in "saturation mode" part of the article I have provided?

Comment: Also, if \$ V_{CE} \$ can be less than \$ V_{CE(sat)} \$ to be saturated, then why there is a parameter named \$ V_{CE(sat)} \$ anyway? Even the name \$ V_{CE(sat)} \$ suggests that: "To be saturated, \$ V_{CE} \ge V_{CE(sat)} \$ ".

Comment: I scanned the article. I did not see any error, but I didn't read it carefully. Does the article actually say that Vce must be greater than Vce (sat) for the transistor to be in saturation? I don't think so. Just look at the quadrant graph at the beginning. You should not think of Vce(sat) sat as being part of the definition of saturation. It is a performance characteristic of the transistor. The definition of saturation in a BJT is when both junctions are forward biased.

Comment: Basically you have the inequality backwards. If saturated, then Vce <= Vce(sat).

Comment: Under "Saturation Mode" heading, in the paragraph that starts with "Another reality bummer: ..." it is implied that \$ V_{CE} \$ must be greater than \$ V_{CE(sat)} \$ . Do I get it wrong? Doesn't the article imply that?

Comment: I don't see that implication. It says "...VC must be slightly greater than VE (but both still less than VB) to get the transistor in saturation mode."

Comment: But it says: "This value means that VC must be slightly greater than VE (but both still less than VB) to get the transistor in saturation mode." Where the word "this" refers to \$ V_{CE(sat)} \$ . Am I wrong?

Comment: So it means: To be in saturation, \$ 0 < V_{CE} < V_{CE(sat)} \$, provided that \$ V_{BE} > V_{th} \$. Do I get it right?

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct. However, I prefer the simple definition, which says that base-emitter junction and base collector junction are both forward biased.

Answer (score 1):

> So *per voltages*, we should be in the saturation mode but \$V_{CE}\$ is less than \$V_{CE(sat)}\$, so we cannot be in saturation mode either.

This is the troublesome part.  When \$ V_{CE} > V_{CE}(sat)\$ you are NOT saturated, but in the linear region.  Think about if the transistor is OFF, and the emitter is grounded -- \$ V_{CE} \$ would be V+, thus big,\$ V_E \$would be at ground, \$V_{CE} \$ at its max, and the transistor is off.  As collector current grows, there is a bigger voltage drop across a load on the collector or emitter, forcing \$V_C \$ closer to \$ V_E \$, lowering \$ V_{CE}\$.  The bigger the current, the bigger the effect.

Thus, \$V_{BE}> V_{Th} \$ and \$V_{CE}<V_{CE}(sat)\$ is a transistor in saturation mode.

See the first figure in http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-071j-introduction-to-electronics-signals-and-measurement-spring-2006/lecture-notes/20_bjt_2.pdf
[image]

Comment: I couldn't understand the first paragraph of the answer but isn't \$ V_{BE} > V_{th} AND V_{CE} < V_{CE(sat)}\$ in saturation mode contradicts with what is written in the "saturation mode" part of the article in the link I have provided? (I am assuming the information in the article is correct. Please inform me if you see any mistakes in the article)

Comment: Because the article states that usual values for \$ V_{th} \$ are around 0.6V and usual values for \$ V_{CE(sat)} \$ are around 0.2V. I mean: It is my assumption that \$ V_{CE(sat)} \$ should be less than \$ V_{th} \$. I am not sure whether if this is indeed the case. I will clarify this in the question.

Comment: I think now I get it. You say: "When \$ V_{CE} > V_{CE(sat)} \$ you are NOT saturated but in the linear region." But is what you really mean: "When \$ V_{CE} > V_{CE(sat)} \; AND \; V_{BE} > V_{th} \$ you are NOT saturated but in the linear region."? Assuming what you mean is the latter, then this time, the requirement for active (linear) region given in the link is wrong. The link says that to be in the linear region, \$ V_{BE} > 0 \; AND \; V_{BC} < 0 \$ but consider the following case:

Comment: \$ V_{CE(sat)} = 0.2V \; AND \; V_{th} = 0.6V \$ for a transistor. And let \$ V_{BE} = 1V \; AND \; V_{CE} = 0.4V \$. Per what you say, we should be in the linear region since \$ V_{CE} > V_{CE(sat)} \; AND \; V_{BE} > V_{th} \$ but it is not the case that \$ V_{BC} < 0 \$. So we can be in the linear region even without satisfying \$ V_{BE} > 0 \; AND \; V_{BC} < 0 \$.

Comment: @Utku You are seriously over complicating this, and it's because the tutorial you're reading simply isn't very good.  Nothing happens unless Vbe is forward biased, as you are in cutoff.  If Vbe is forward biased, the transister is either in the linear region,or in saturation.  I highly recommend going to the lecture I pointed to and forget that sparkfun deal.